# Internal ArangoDB error on simple REPLACE_NTH query

Tags: arangodb, aql

In a completely empty arangodb instance (3.7.9), I first create the empty collection: `temp`.
Then, I run two queries:

```
INSERT {v:[1]} INTO temp
```

and

```
FOR doc IN temp
RETURN REPLACE_NTH(doc.v, 0, 0, 0)
```

The first query, creates a single entry in temp. The second query, should return [1]. However, instead I get the error:

```
Query: Expecting Array slice (while executing) (exception location: /work/ArangoDB/arangod/RestHandler/RestCursorHandler.cpp:320). Please report this error to arangodb.com
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, yes, this is a bug. Please use the issue tracker at https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/ to report issues, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bugreport and should be filed via  https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/

Comment: to be more precise this already has been reported as an issue https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/13632 (twice...) Please use one communication channel and stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in v3.7.10, see https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/13632